# What is wrong with my Catalan Number logic?

Tags: c, algorithm, math, catalan

I wanted to write a code for **Catalan Numbers**.Catalan Numbers are defined as follows:

`C(n) = 2n C n/(n+1)`. But instead of computing `(2n C n)` I wanted to calculate the catalan numbers bottom up using the following facts:

```
Catalan(n) =    
2n! /n! * n! * (n+1)  

Catalan(n+1) =  
2*(n+1)  
--------------------------- =    
(n+1)! * (n+1)! * ((n+1)+1)  

(2n+2) * (2n+1) * 2n!    
------------------------------- =  
(n+1) * n! * (n+1) * n! * (n+2)    

(2n+2) * (2n+1) * 2n!    
----------------------------------- =    
(n+1) * (n+2) * n! * n! * (n+1)    

(2n+2) * (2n+1)    
--------------- * Catalan(n)      
(n+1) * (n+2)
```

Now utilizing the above fact this is my following code:

```
int catalan(int n)
{
    if (n == 1)
       return 1 //since c(1)=1 is my base case
    else
       return (((2*n+2) * (2*n+1))/((n+1)*(n+2))) * catalan(n-1)
}
```

Now,my question is why does the above function return 12 when my input is 4 .It should return 14 because c(4)=14.

Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: What is (2n C n) supposed to mean?

Comment: @Jens Schauder binomal coeffiecnt: 2n over n

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an error in your formula. Your formula is for calculating c(n+1) yet your input is n. This can be fixed by decreasing the value of n by one before using it in the calculation:

```
int catalan(int n)
{
    if (n == 1)
       return 1 //since c(1)=1 is my base case
    else
       n=n-1
       return (((2*n+2) * (2*n+1))/((n+1)*(n+2))) * catalan(n)
}
```

**Edit:** As pointed out by abeln, the code above will fail due to integer division dropping the remainder. Use the code below instead:

```
int catalan(int n)
{
    if (n == 1)
       return 1 //since c(1)=1 is my base case
    else
       n=n-1
       return ((catalan(n) * (2*n+2) * (2*n+1))/((n+1)*(n+2)))
}
```

Comment: The code here will produce incorrect values, due to truncation in the integer division.

Answer (score 9):

Even though the original expression for `C(n)` might be wrong, the actual recurrence

[image]

is **correct**.

You can further simplify that to

[image]

But that gives you `C(n+1)` in terms of `C(n)`. What you want is `C(n)` in terms of `C(n-1)`. Plug in `n-1` to get

[image]

Also note that in order to prevent the integer division from truncating your result, you need to multiply first and then divide.

```
int catalan(int n) {
  if (n == 1)
    return 1; 
  else
    return 2 * (2*n - 1) * catalan(n-1) / (n+1);
}
```

**EDIT:** if the values of the [image] need to be used frequently and not just calculated once, it's probably a good idea to use [memoization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization), to avoid calculating them more than once.

Additionally, notice that due to the large growth rate, the Catalan numbers quickly overflow any of the predefined integer data types `C` has.

Answer (score 4):

According to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number the recurrence formula is:

`C(n+1)=2(2n+1)/(n+1) * C(n)` or `C(n)=2(2(n-1)+1)/n * C(n-1)`

I think you have forgotten this transformation from `C(n+1)` to `C(n)`.

Comment: That's what he's got - he just replaced (n+1)! with (n+1)*n!

Comment: The formula is correct, there is just a mind lapse in the programming.

Comment: Indeed, the problem is not there.

Answer (score 3):

When you go from the mathematical expression to code, you are implicitly replacing n with n-1 in the Catalan() parts, but not in the expression itself.  So you are computing the multiplier for value N and multiplying it by C(N-1).  Try substituting N-1 for N in your equation, which leads to:

```
int catalan(int n)
{
    if (n == 1)
       return 1 //since c(1)=1 is my base case
    else
       return (((2*n) * (2*n-1))/((n)*(n+1))) * catalan(n-1)
}
```

Comment: have you tested your function?

Answer (score 0):

In your formula, you have

```
         (2n)!
C(n) = ----------------
        (n+1)! * n! * n!
```

when in fact the Catalan Numbers are defined as

```
         (2n)!
C(n) = ----------------
        (n+1)! * n!
```

i.e. you have one factorial on the denominator too much

Comment: its the same because `2n c n /n+1 = 2n!/n!*n!*(n+1)` .Now, the denominator has been simplified as `n+1! = n!*(n+1)` and that has been replaced there .Its all the same.